# Time-in and time-out exceeding minutes

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures

need help.

scenario: I have a time in and time out in my DTR system. My problem is, lets say employee1 TIMED-IN: 9:20 am and TIMED-out : 6:00, so basically his total work hrs is 8:40 hrs, however some of the employees are taking advantage of this silly system so what they do, they TIMED-in :9:20 am(and stayed a little bit longer so that they can complete the 9 hrs requirement work) TIMED-out: 6:20 pm.

PROBLEM: what can i do to cut or not to include the exceeding 20 min in computing the total work hrs.

Technology: MySql, stored proc

Sample script but this is only for lates:

TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, `dtr1`.`TIMEIN`,`dtr1`.`TIMEOUT`)as test,
         CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `dtr1`.`TIMEIN`,`dtr1`.`TIMEOUT`) < 540                         THEN 540 - TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `dtr1`.`TIMEIN`,`dtr1`.`TIMEOUT`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should explain your goal more clearly by providing formal rules (formulas, not necessarily in any programming language) for computing the needed result.

Comment: If you want to not pay employees for their time, you would have to ask them to volunteer their time for free, which they can decline legally.  You have to pay workers a minimum rate for the entire time that they work (from clock in to clock out)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (untested):

```
CREATE FUNCTION example_function()
BEGIN
RETURN INT; 
DECLARE minutes_worked INT;
DECLARE maximum_minutes_in_day INT;


SET maximum_minutes_in_day = 540;
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, dtr1.TIMEIN,dtr1.TIMEOUT) into minutes_worked;

IF minutes_worked > maximum_minutes_in_day THEN
SET minutes_worked = maximum_minutes_in_day;
END IF

RETURN(minutes_worked);
END
```

Comment: Thanks richard. in this case you dont need to compute you just assign the 540 even if they exceed 540..thanks